# Android Studio 2.0 IllegalArgumentException: button doesn't exist 0

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception, android-studio-2.0, android-studio-2.1

Using android studio 2.0 stable version and previous version 1.5 I on Ubuntu, I always get this exception all the time. Any ideas?

It appears in the `EventLog` [image: This right here]

Comment: Please provide more context on where and when you see this.

Comment: In the dialog window that appears on the right of AS and also on the Event Log on the lower right corner

Comment: Can you edit your question with these details and copy and paste the entire text into it?  Also, did you the usual clean and rebuild of the project?

Comment: Also, did you upgrade your android gradle plugin to version 2.0.0?

Comment: I have all upgrades on my AS 2.0. The only message I got on the Event Log is the following. I submited the bug to AS team too.

6:13:45 PM IllegalArgumentException: button doesn't exist 0
6:13:49 PM IllegalArgumentException: button doesn't exist 0
6:14:26 PM IllegalArgumentException: button doesn't exist 0

Thanks for your time @DougStevenson