# IllegalArgumentException: button doesn't exist 0 in android studio 2.1 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

[My question has been asked a few days ago by others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523377/android-studio-2-0-illegalargumentexception-button-doesnt-exist-0). But there is no answer and the question was not write clear. So I ask it again.

When I want to use emulator to run my application, the Gradle could be built successfully. But there is another error, following is the event log:

```
8:10:05 AM Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
8:11:55 AM Gradle build finished in 1m 49s 837ms
8:14:32 AM Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
8:16:05 AM Gradle build finished in 1m 33s 529ms
8:16:20 AM IllegalArgumentException: button doesn't exist 0
```

Can anyone help me figure it out? thanks in advance.

**Addition:**

OS: ubuntu 14.04

jdk: orcale 1.8

Answer (score 0):

After enabling virtualization technology in bios, and the problem resolved. Hope helpful.

Comment: mine is enabled but the ide gets stuck at refreshing project